# how to get php comment lines ,code lines count in ruby on rails using regular expressions in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to rails , currently i am working on code statistics for php,javascript/coffeescript repositories using ruby where i have a requirement to get no of coded lines and comment lines(single line and multi line comments) of php and javascript and coffeescript files using regular expressions . can any one help on this , thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds more like a Ruby question, not Rails.

Comment: thank you for your response ,yes i am using ruby to get comment lines in php and javascript files ,i am getting single line comments but i am facing problem with getting multiline comments(/* ... */) can you help me regard this one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is my man:

```
f = File.open("test.php")

loc = 0
comments = 0
while line = f.gets
  if commented ||= line.match(/^\/\*/)
    commented = nil if line.match(/\*\/$/)
    comments += 1
  elsif line.match(/^\s*\/\//)
    comments += 1
  else
    loc +=1 unless line.match(/^\s*\n/)
  end
end

puts loc
puts comments
```

This works for:

```
//line comments
/* inline block comments */
/* multi
line
comments */
```

How it works:

- You open the file
- Initialize the counters in 0
- Go trough each line with gets and assign it to the line variable
- If the line matches the beggining of a block comment set the commented variable
- Add 1 to comments variable
- If commented is set, search for the end of comment and set commented to nil if found
- Else if comment block not opened and "//" is found add 1 to comments
- Else add 1 to loc unless it's an "empty" line